# Recieving multiple packets in one connection Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When reading a characteristic of ble in android device or even subscribing to it, I receive 2 packets at the same time but I know that these data are not complete because when decoding them i find a part of the data sent by the characteristic so I think that the problem is that the ble write multiple packets to the characteristic at the same connection interval but the android recieve only 2 of them
I need to know how to receive all of them so I can have the full data at the end ?
This is the code of onCharacteristicChanged method

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (HEART_RATE_READING_CHAR.equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
            byte[] char_float_value = characteristic.getValue();
            String s="";
            for(int i=0;i<char_float_value.length;i++){
                s=s +String.format("%02x", char_float_value[i])+" ";
            }
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
            Log.e("_____________", "_____________");
            Log.d("TAG", s);
                handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null,MSG_HEARTRATE,char_float_value[14]));
        }
    }
```

And these are the packets i receive at the same time
[Packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npjw1.png)

Comment: Did you required `byte[]`? You can directly get String value from `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` and don't required `for` loop.

Comment: that loop was required to convert values from byte to hex because i need them in hex form

Comment: onCharacteristicChanged will give you all notifcations sent by the BLE device